# How to encode # in Azure Logic Apps OData Orderby Query?

Tags: odata, azure-logic-apps

I have an Excel Online (Business) spreadsheet with a 'Box #' column. I am using the Excel "List rows present in a table" connector and I would like to order by the "Box #" column.

However, when I try to enter it, I either get a syntax error or a column not found error.

"Box #": Syntax error '#' not allowed at this position.
"Box_x0020_#": Syntax error '#' not allowed at this position.
"Box_x0020__x0025_": Column not found.
"Box *x0025*": "Syntax error at position 11 in 'Box *x0023*"

Does anyone know how to properly encode the '#' character for use in an OrderBy clause of a SharePoint Logic App Connector? Or better yet, the missing online reference.

Comment: You could try  a double single quotation, `''`.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I tried that too. ""Syntax error: character '#' is not valid at position 5 in 'Box''# desc'"

Answer (score 0):

try *x0023* instead of *x0025*

*x0025* is % according to
https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/